# Accessing WordPress MySQL Database via Data Connection in Visual Studio 2010 using C#

Tags: categories, database, mysql, wp-config

So I've Googled and followed countless tutorials, read documentation on MySQL, Visual Studio, WordPress, and Plesk. I try to leave posting on this site as the final option and it seems it has come to that.

As simply put as possible, I want to display the list of categories from my WordPress blog on another ASP.NET/C# website that I have. There isn't an RSS of the names of the categories specifically otherwise I would have used the XML from the RSS feed with XSLT to display the category list that way. I came to the conclusion that I had to access my WordPress database (where the category names are stored) directly from my other website.

To do so, I've downloaded and installed the MySQL Connector Net 6.5.4 on my localmachine (C: Drive) allowing the "MySQL Database" option to be available when adding a Data Connection in Visual Studio. I also, downloaded the 'noinstall' of the MySQL Connector Net 6.5.4 by selecting ".NET & MONO" from the "Select Platform:" dropdown on MySql.com in order to add a reference to the DLL in my C# code.

I get the same error when either attempting to run the code or adding a data connection. Adding the data connection was originally to test the actual connection to the database after I got the error from running the code.

Error: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Below is the code I have in my 'Default.aspx.cs' file:

```
...
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
...
        String MyConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;UID=testusername;PASSWORD=testpassword;DATABASE=testdbname;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM wp_terms wt " +
                      "INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wt.term_id=wtt.term_id " +
                      "WHERE wtt.taxonomy='category' ORDER BY wt.name";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            string thisrow = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                thisrow += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",";
                Label1.Text += thisrow;
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

At this point, I am convinced that the problem lies with the credentials that I am entering in String MyConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;UID=testusername;PASSWORD=testpassword;DATABASE=testdbname;"; or when attempting to 'Add a Data Connection'. However, I checked the wp-config.php file within my WordPress installation in the blog's root directory and am, therefore, positive that I am providing the correct credentials. The only one I am slightly unsure of is the Database server name [localhost].

Is there something else I am not doing correctly? Is it possible the WordPress databases don't allow for remote access?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

P.S. I've posted this question on Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the port? By default, MySQL listens on port 3306.  So give `SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;UID=testusername;PASSWORD=testpassword;DATABASE=testdbname;` a try for your connection string.

Comment: I have. I have tried several variants of the connection string. No luck. Same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There isn't an RSS of the names of the categories specifically otherwise I would have used the XML from the RSS feed with XSLT to display the category list that way.

There is a handy function named [`add_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed). You can create any feed or  other output with it. Should be useful in your case. And it is pretty simple too.

#### Sample plugin

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Category Feed
 * Description: XML output for the categories located on /catxml/
 */

add_action( 'init', array ( 'T5_Cat_Feed', 'init' ) );

class T5_Cat_Feed
{
    public static function init()
    {
        add_feed( 'catxml', array ( __CLASS__, 'display' ) );
    }

    public static function display()
    {
        $args = array(
            'hide_empty'               => 0,
            'hierarchical'             => 0,
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category'
        );
        $cats = get_categories( $args );

        if ( empty ( $cats ) or ! is_array( $cats ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        header( 'Content-Type: text/xml' );
        print '<categories>';

        foreach ( $cats as $cat )
        {
            $url = get_category_link( $cat->term_id );
            print "<category>
<name>$cat->cat_name</name>
<id>$cat->term_id</id>
<url>$url</url>
<description>$cat->category_description</description>
<parent>$cat->parent</parent>
<count>$cat->count</count>
</category>"
            ;
        }
        print '</categories>';
    }
}
```

Install as a plugin on your blog, visit the permalink settings page once to refresh the rewrite cache, and go to `example.com/catxml/` or `example.com/?feed=catxml`. You get a simple XML file with category data here.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks toscho. However, I am new to WordPress development. This code isn't something I should add into my functions.php file? I should add it as a plugin? How do I do that?

Comment: Save the code as something like categoryfeed.php and then upload the file via the Upload page in the Add New Plugin section of my Dashboard?

Comment: @JSco Yes, exactly.

Comment: If I may inquire about some of the specifics in the code you provided for the plugin, what is the significance of... (1)"T5" in the class title?
(2)"CLASS" in the first parameter of the array in the add_feed function? Am I correct in assuming I can use the code you provided exactly as is, without making any changes?

Comment: `T5` is my prefix, because I [prefix everything](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/). `__CLASS__` is a magic constant with the current classes name. Callbacks which are static methods need the class name as the first parameter. The plugin is running as is, see [this example](http://wptest.toscho.de/catxml/).

Comment: You da man toscho! My site's main purpose will be to showcase my web development skills as much as possible so I will have explanations for everything I add to improve it. I will be happy to reference you in explanation for how I created a plugin to get a custom feed for my list of categories. Would you mind if I posted with links to your user profile here on stack exchange as well as your website, facebook, google+, twitter pages, etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when trying to install the plugin on my Dashboard: `The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature` I'm not sure what the Central Dir Record signature is? I tried uploading the file with the closing `?>` at the end and without. I named the file _cateogryfeed.php_.

Comment: Oh, the uploader takes zip files only. So either use the FTP/SSH upload or pack the file into a zip container first. Backlinks are always welcome. :)

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have known from the theme uploader. I figured you would appreciate linking to you but just wanted to check (some people are strange). Although I successfully converted my XHTML template to a WordPress/PHP theme, as you can see, PHP is very new to me still. Thanks again for your help. Not sure how long it took you to drum up that code (probably not long at all) but I appreciate it none the less.

Comment: Sorry, toscho. I'm getting a `404 Not Found` error when I try to navigate to [my blog home url /catxml](http://www.jackscotty.com/blog/catxml)

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer. Follow each step. ;)

Comment: `Install as a plugin on your blog, visit the permalink settings page once to refresh the rewrite cache, and go to example.com/catxml/. You get a simple XML file with category data here.` I saved the categoryfeed.xml file to a zip file (categoryfeed.zip), uplaoded it as a new plugin to my blog, clicked on the permalink section in settings, and then navigated to http://www.jackscotty.com/blog/catxml. I get a 404 Not Found...

Comment: Well, you have not set up pretty permalinks. Use http://www.jackscotty.com/blog/?feed=catxml then.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you. I actually had the permalinks set up as just the category names for categories and just tag names for tags and just the post name for posts the first time. When I tried to go to /catxml it said it didn't recognize that category... so I switched it back. It works great thanks toscho!

Comment: We have a [special tool for new questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). ;)

Comment: [See related question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/51938/12650)